# autofs --force unmounts /proc

Tags: centos, upgrade, proc, autofs

Historically I've seen autofs get into situtations where `systemctl restart autofs` will hang indefinitely due to stale nfs handles.

As a result I've employed the `--force` option to make `autofs` play a little less nicely.

The other day I upgraded one system from CentOS 7.7 to CentOS 7.8. It did not go as I expected.

When starting `autofs` my `/proc` got unmounted - with my machine becoming a potatoe.

After som troubleshooting I realized that the culprit was my deploy of:

```
# grep OPTIONS /etc/sysconfig/autofs
OPTIONS="--force"
```

That it caused `/proc` to be unmounted must surely be a bug? Or am I missing something here?

The setting has worked without unmountig `/proc` on all previous minor versions of CentOS 7 I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typical XY problem. Look it up, it's really instructive. ;-)

> due to stale nfs handles.

This is your problem, that's what you should solve. `mount.nfs(8)` has some really nice options on what to do in case of a timeout.

Also consider setting up the `magic-sysrq` keys, so you have a way to get out of a stuck shutdown.

Comment: Thanks Han. I don’t agree. I just removed the force, I’m good. I’m just trying to shine a light on the change in autofs. I can’t fathom a time where autofs _should_ nuke /proc.

Comment: True, that's something it really shouldn't do.